# Как context попадает в name,html, через include

Tags: django

Я сейчас прохожу курс основ по Django у меня наверняка глупый вопрос, но меня он вводит в замешательство сейчас.

**Вопрос:** Есть некий index.html в него мы через класс News(ListView) кидаем некий context,выводим новости итд.

Я хочу вынести пагинатор в Templates/inc/_paginator.html и запихать его в конец index.html

Все ясно - я добавляю `paginate_by = 4` в класс. И тут я должен начать оперировать объектом paje_obj в файле _paginator.html... Чтобы эту пагинацию там создать.

Вопрос- каким образом _paginator.html вообще получает объект paje_obj? если в классе

```
News(ListView):
template_name = 'blog/index.html'
```

передача происходит в момент вызова `{% include 'inc/_paginator.html' %}` ?

Ну если кого насмешил, то не за что

Comment: вы наверное сможете понять, посмотреть как работает например функция `render`. В общем `context` передается из основного файла в доставленные, если не указано обратно, хотя последнее вроде касается только шаблонных тегов.

Comment: Так вы же подключаете _paginator.html к шаблону index.html. Вот так и получает.

Comment: Для меня это было не очевидно. Была мысль, что нужно передавать туда каким- то образом дату. Спасибо за ваши ответы.